# LISTAGG within CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

Is it possible to use listagg in the "Then" stage of a case statement?

I've been getting errors related to grouping and parenthesis even though i have grouped by every other selected field.

My case statement currently looks like:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN allergen.type = 'KTC' THEN listagg(allergen.name, ',') within group (order by allergen.name) END) AS Allergen_KTC
```

which works perfectly when used as below instead:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN allergen.type = 'KTC' THEN allergen.name END) AS Allergen_KTC
```

I think i'm missing something here.

Comment: Case _expression_. (A case statement is something else.)

Answer (score 1):

Would vice-versa do any good?

```
listagg(case when allergen.type = 'KTC' then allergen.name end, ',') 
  within group (order by allergen.name)
```

Example:

```
SQL> select listagg(case when deptno = 10 then ename end, ',')
  2    within group (order by ename) result
  3  from emp;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------
CLARK,KING,MILLER

SQL>
```

Comment: Weird, with this method i'm getting a lot of duplicates in the Listagg, all i selected was the ID and listagg, grouped by ID.